# "error: unable to find library -latomic" when using clang

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, clang, pdfium

I am trying to build a project ([PDFium](https://github.com/benjinus/android-support-pdfium/blob/master/BUILD.md)) using clang.
It keeps giving me this error

```
ld.lld: error: unable to find library -latomic
clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

I have these installed on my system

```
libatomic_ops 7.6.14-1
clang 14.0.6-2
lib32-clang 14.0.6-1
libatomic1
```

And about LD_LIBRARY_PATH

```
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib64:/usr/lib32:/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib
$ sudo ldconfig
```

I have tried it on Debian, Arch and Ubuntu.

Comment: removed "the title says it all", because a) I have question and so that's not true and b) if it were true, it'd be redundant.

Comment: Questions: 1. What platform are you building this one? 2. the build system will probably print the full clang invocation line that leads to this error. That's critical info without which we can't help you.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I have tried it on Debian, Arch and Ubuntu.

Comment: The full message is a mess, but you can find it here: https://www.heypasteit.com/clip/0IYWY5

Though, replace libmodpdfium with pdfsdk since I change the name in the last run in hope it will make a difference.

Comment: um, why are you using some third party clang/llvm? That certainly is something very important here, and means saying that you're doing this on some Linux distro is not even half the picture!

Comment: you'll have to describe the system on which you're building in much more detail, sorry.

Comment: I have a fresh install of Ubuntu, I installed the following packages: build-essential git subversion pkg-config python libtool cmake glib2.0-dev libatspi2.0-dev wget

Then ran the script. When the error happened I installed libatomic1 but it didn't make a difference.

I can answer further questions, but I don't know what to mention right now.

Also, this logged some of my tries to solve the problem: https://github.com/benjinus/android-support-pdfium/issues/11

Comment: do you have the development packages for libatomic installed?

Comment: @AlanBirtles I thought this was it, but I installed libatomic-ops-dev and same error.